# Unable to set button on scroll view in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm setting a scroll view and on that view I have two buttons, but, the buttons don't show up on the image view. When I set the scroll view. I want a button on the image:

```
-(void)addScrollView{

    scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1280,960);

    CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];

    scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,758);

    imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:

                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"IPHome Page Final.jpg"]];

    [scrollview addSubview:imageview];

    scrollview.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;

    scrollview.maximumZoomScale = 3;

    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageview.frame.size.width,

                                          imageview

                                          .frame.size.height);

    scrollview.delegate = self;
    [imageview addSubview:CameraButton];
    [imageview addSubview:SoundButton];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];

}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: There is no buttons in your pasted code. Could be the reason why there is no buttons on your screen...

Comment: -(IBAction)CameraSound:(id)sender
{
    [Capture stop];
    
    NSString *strPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"takephotoshutter" ofType:@"wav"];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath];
    NSError *err;
    Capture = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&err];
    [Capture play];
}
This is my button code.

Comment: ohh....i did not set button frame ..

Comment: but i create button with drag and drop.

Comment: Then you have to create an outlet for it. In your case it is easier to create it programatically as you want to add it to a `UIImageView`

Answer (score 0):

Your code handles avents happens on button (such as touch up inside/outside ..etc) You have to create the buttons first. Create a button either programatically via `UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)]` or add it to Interface builder and create an `IBOutlet` for it.